# Inconsistent interaction in menu between <li> list item and <a> anchor tag

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Why is the dropdown `ul` in 'Menu Item 2' not being aligned absolutely to the top of its parent `li` element?

With the dropdown `ul` CSS set as:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

I would expect it to be covering from the top left of the parent element, i.e. covering it completely.

Some confusing symptoms:

I want the parent menu to be clickable AND have a dropdown in some cases. So where there is a dropdown, the parent menu `<li>` has an `<a>` that is padded to increase the clickable area. This also increases the containing `<li>`, since the `li:hover` shows the same padded area. This works as desired.

However, when the dropdown is shown and aligned to `<li>`, `<li>` seems to be in the position *before* it was expanded by `<a>`. When I check in a browser (Chrome and Firefox) the `<li>` element is not actually filling the same space as the `<a>` and so the dropdown appears some amount *below* the where I want it.

I understand that I can use top:SOME_NEGATIVE_OFFSET in the absolutely positioned dropdown but this feels hacky and I'd like to understand what's going on?

It's my first post, please go easy on me :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DropDownTest</title>
<style>
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
li>a{
  padding:1rem;
  background-color:grey;
}
li>a:hover{
  background-color:lightgray;
}
.mainbar>li{
 float:left;
}
li.hasDrop:hover>ul{
  display:block;
}
.dropContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; /*not working as expected*/
  left:0;
  margin:0;/*thought this might have helped but no*/
  padding:0;
  z-index:1;
  list-style:none;
  min-width:100%;
}
.dropContent>li>a{
  display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul class="mainbar">
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="hasDrop">
      <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
      <ul class="dropContent">
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens beacuse your `a` element is getting padding as inline element.

Modify this rule:

```
li>a {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block; /* this*/
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

li>a {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block; /* this*/
}

li>a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.mainbar>li {
  float: left;
}

li.hasDrop:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.dropContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /*not working as expected*/
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*thought this might have helped but no*/
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.dropContent>li>a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="mainbar">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    
    <li class="hasDrop">
      <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
      <ul class="dropContent">
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So after experimenting some more with your solution (which works) I still don't understand the interaction between the elements. If the `li` is the parent of the hidden `ul` content, why does styling `a` to a block change where the dropdown shows. Shouldn't it be looking to `li`, which is already a block element?

Comment: If you use an inspector on your browser, you see that  `<ul class="mainbar">` has not the same height to li children due to the padding in `a` element. padding inside inline elements not increase the height.